# One of the few or one of the only

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to tell my friend that he is among the very few who can make me smile. 
Here's what sounds more natural to me:
You're one of the few people who is good at it(making me smile).
Or should I say "you're one of the only people who is good at it" instead?
Thank you!

Comment: There are so many issues with "one of the only people who is", I don't even know where to begin. Just don't use it. At any rate, the *is* must be an *are*. *Who* is plural here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with your first instinct, don't over-think it and do it now ;))

Comment: The questioner provides two options from which she asks us to choose. By 'go with your first instinct' I meant choose the first of your two options. I'd have thought that was pretty obvious actually.

Comment: OK, point taken - but all you've provided is a personal opinion, unsupported by any explanation let alone authoritative evidence. The system had flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**", and my vote to delete triggered the automatic response comment. Now that your answer has been accepted, I suspect it's safe from automatic deletion, but it remains at risk of downvotes, and on SE sites too many negatively-voted answers can lead to automatic restrictions.

Comment: Note that an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to improve its content - at the very least, by explaining why this is the *right* answer. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: Lastly, you're saying that "option one" is correct English. This is **incorrect**. As @RegDwigнt notes in his [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473497/one-of-the-few-or-one-of-the-only/473500?noredirect=1#comment1143261_473497), it should use the plural *are*. The first option also includes a typo (no space before the bracket). At the very least, these deficiencies need to be pointed out, or the *correct* sentence included, in your answer.

Comment: Nowhere did I say option one was correct English. She wants to be kind to her friend, not pass an exam. I thought I'd be kind to her. And you can't be serious if you think I'm going to spend my time pointing out obvious missing spaces in questions typed hastily on phones. But otherwise your points taken too, and thank you for the advice.

Comment: I appreciate your position. I think the problem arises with the question itself, which belongs not here (where we address the *correctness of the wording*) but on our sister site [interpersonal.se] (where they would address *how to go about expressing this sentiment to her friend*). Unfortunately, your laudably kind response has to be assessed against the standards for *this* site, since this is where it's been posted. :-)